# Generating a valid Oauth JWT for use with the Adobe User Management API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth, adobe, jwt

I'm trying to make calls to the Adobe User Management API from within Google Apps Script but I'm having trouble generating valid JWTs.

I've completed the "One time setup" on [this page](https://adobe-apiplatform.github.io/umapi-documentation/en/UM_Authentication.html) - I created an Integration and a service account, created a self-signed certificate, copied the API key/credentials, etc.

I'm getting this error when using the JWTs that I've created:

```
{"error_code":"401013","message":"Oauth token is not valid"}
```

Here's the code that I wrote using [this page](https://www.adobe.io/apis/cloudplatform/console/authentication/createjwt.html) as a guide and using the [OAuth2 for Apps Script library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) to create the token:

```
var DOMAIN_NAME                          = 'xxxxxxxxxx.com';
var ADOBE_API_CLIENT_ID_API_KEY          = '1e0a15027994xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var ADOBE_API_CLIENT_SECRET              = '5528fe1f-3a1c-4exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var ADOBE_ORGANIZATION_ID                = '79FAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@AdobeOrg';
var ADOBE_JWT_SUBJECT                    = '4A8Bxxxxxxxxxx@techacct.adobe.com';
var ADOBE_JWT_AUDIENCE                   = 'https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/c/1e0a15027994xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var ADOBE_API_PRIVATE_KEY                = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
var ADOBE_IO_CONSOLE_GENERATED_JWT_TOKEN = 'eyJhbGciOixxxxxxxxxx.ew0KICAgICJleHAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var ADOBE_API_BASE_URL                   = 'https://usermanagement.adobe.io/v2/usermanagement/';

function getAdobeUser(email) {

var payload = {
    "exp": new Date().getTime() + 3600,
    "iss": ADOBE_ORGANIZATION_ID,
    "sub": ADOBE_JWT_SUBJECT,
    "https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/s/ent_user_sdk": true,
    "aud": ADOBE_JWT_AUDIENCE
    };

  var requestBody                = {};
  requestBody.method             = "POST";
  requestBody.payload            = payload;
  requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;

  var service = OAuth2.createService('adobe')
      .setTokenUrl(ADOBE_JWT_AUDIENCE)
      .setClientId(ADOBE_ORGANIZATION_ID)
      .setClientSecret(ADOBE_API_CLIENT_SECRET)
      .setSubject(ADOBE_JWT_SUBJECT)
      .setPrivateKey(ADOBE_API_PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setScope('https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/s/ent_user_sdk')

  var signedJwtToken = service.createJwt_(); 
  
  var url = 'https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/exchange/jwt?client_id=' + ADOBE_API_CLIENT_ID_API_KEY + '&client_secret=' + ADOBE_API_CLIENT_SECRET + '&jwt_token=' + signedJwtToken;
// var url = 'https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/exchange/jwt?client_id=' + ADOBE_API_CLIENT_ID_API_KEY + '&client_secret=' + ADOBE_API_CLIENT_SECRET + '&jwt_token=' + ADOBE_IO_CONSOLE_GENERATED_JWT_TOKEN;

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
    var access_token = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('failed while getting access_token: ' + e.message);
  }
  var user = null;
  
  var url = ADOBE_API_BASE_URL + 'organizations/' + ADOBE_ORGANIZATION_ID + '/users/' + encodeURIComponent(email) + '?domain=' + DOMAIN_NAME;
  
  var requestBody = {
     headers: { "X-Api-Key": ADOBE_API_CLIENT_ID_API_KEY, "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token },
     method: "GET";
     muteHttpExceptions: false;
  };
  
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
    user = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  } catch(e) {
      console.log('failed while getting user: ' + e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

I am fairly sure that the payload being sent is correct because there is a panel in the Adobe I/O console where they show you a sample payload (I've made sure the values match my payload) and you can paste in the private key to generate a JWT:

[image]

When I copy the JWT that's generated here and use that instead of the one generated by the Oauth2 library, the token works and the API calls work.

So then I tried changing the `exp` value on that page to `1840060800` (10 years in the future) and generating a new JWT, and that one works as well, but it still expires after 24 hours, despite the higher value I set for `exp`.

Comment: your secret key is visible in the image

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the oauth2 apps script client library is tailored for use with Google APIs. This library thus requires that a base url be set.

However Adobe's OAuth2 implementation looks to be a bit different as it only requires one endpoint for the JWT exchange.

You probably have to create a custom implementation to manage your refresh tokens. Also the Adobe documentation states that expiration is capped at 24 hours (setting it to 10 years won't help); so you'll need a system that can refresh your tokens after they've expired.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a Google App script library for integrating Adobe Analytics API. It manages authentication and function calls for you in one package.

Document here: https://github.com/weizhen/adobeanalyticsclient
Feedback is welcomed!

To get token explicitly with the library:

```
function getAdobeAnalyticsClient () {
  return AdobeAnalyticsClient.init()
  .setClientId('') // set client ID
  .setClientSecret('') // set client secret
  .setPrviatekey('') // string format private key, replace line breaks with /n, generated when Adobe IO integration was created with JWT
  .setIss('') // set iss
  .setSub('') // set sub
  .setAud('') // set aud
  .setTokenLifeSec(); // set bearer token lifetime in seconds
}

function getToken () {
  var client = getAdobeAnalyticsClient();
  if(client.bearerTokenReady()){ // verify bearer token is received when token is exchanged
    Logger.log("Ready");
    Logger.log(client.getBearerToken());
    Logger.log(client.getTokenExpireIn());
  }

}
```